# Recyclerview scrollToPosition does not work

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have tried everything from the answers to the questions on stackoverflow, but I still could not figure this out. In one of my recyclerview, I was able to scroll to the desired position after a click of a button. On a different recyclerview (it was built similar to the first one), I was not able to scroll to the desired position.

This is the code for the recyclerview that worked:

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);

Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button2);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        newFeedRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(2);
    }
});

FeedRecyclerAdapter adapter = new FeedRecyclerAdapter(view.getContext(), allRows);
newFeedRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
newFeedRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
newFeedRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(new VerticalSpaceItemDecorator(30));
newFeedRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

And this is for the recyclerview that did not work:

```
allImageRecycleView.addItemDecoration(new VerticalSpaceItemDecorator(30));
allImageRecycleView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
allImageRecycleView.setHasFixedSize(true);
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new >LinearLayoutManagerWithSmoothScroller(getContext());

Button button = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.button3);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        allImageRecycleView.smoothScrollToPosition(2);
    }
});
layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
allImageRecycleView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

allImageRecycleView.setAdapter(allImageRecyclerAdapter);
```

Thank you so much for reading this.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
layoutManager.scrollToPosition(index);
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. This solution works for the first recyclerview, but not the second. I have been trying to figure it out why.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
layoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(int position, int offset)
```

> scrollToPositionWithOffset(int position, int offset) Scroll to the
>   specified adapter position with the given offset from resolved layout
>   start.

src : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/LinearLayoutManager.html

Comment: Thank you for answering. This solution works for the first recyclerview, but not the second. I have been trying to figure it out why.

Answer (score 0):

May not be relevant to your case but in general:

I find that the problem why scrollToPosition , and others API, does not work is because the dataset is not yet ready. We should call scrollToPosition when the recyclerView has received dataset. To do that, we can use AdapterDataObserver.

```
val adapter = binding.recyclerView.adapter!!
adapter.registerAdapterDataObserver(object : RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver() {
                override fun onItemRangeInserted(positionStart: Int, itemCount: Int) {
                    binding.recyclerView.scrollToPosition(positionStart)
                    adapter.unregisterAdapterDataObserver(this)
                }
```

Similarly, you can override other methods of Class AdapterDataObserver, if needed.