# RecyclerView scroll to top with AsyncListDiffer not working

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-asynclistdiffer, android-diffutils

I am using `RecyclerView` with [`AsyncListDiffer`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/recyclerview/extensions/AsyncListDiffer) (calculates and animates differences between old and new items, all on background thread).

I have a button to sort the list. After I sort it and re-set it to `RecyclerView` using `mDiffer.submitList(items);` I also call `recyclerView.scrollToPosition(0)` or (`smoothScrollToPosition(0)`), but it has no effect.

I think this behaviour is expected, as `AsyncListDiffer` is probably still  calculating differences at the time that `scrollToPosition(0)` is called, so it has no effect. Additionally, by default `AsyncListDiffer` does not scroll back to top, but instead it keeps RecyclerView in the same state.

But how do I tell the `RecyclerView` to scroll to top after `AsyncListDiffer` is done and updates it?

Comment: Have you tried to scroll *before* submitting the new items? Maybe it's not the solution you need, but at least can be useful to know if the operation is failing because `AsyncListDiffer` is still running or because something else.

Comment: I just tried, and it does not help. I also just noticed that when I sort the list and submit it, the `RecyclerView` items are not re-bound (refreshed). I have to pull down a little and then I can see the sorted items. But this might be for another question..

Comment: Maybe this other questions may be of help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41357303/recyclerview-scrolltoposition-does-not-work and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30845742/smoothscrolltoposition-doesnt-work-properly-with-recyclerview And about the re-bound, looks like you may have an issue with stable Ids. Could you provide you Adapter code? Alt. see https://medium.com/@hanru.yeh/recyclerviews-views-are-blinking-when-notifydatasetchanged-c7b76d5149a2

Comment: Bottom line: either disable stable Ids in your adapter `adapter.setHasStableIds(false)` or, better, make sure they are enabled `adapter.setHasStableIds(true)` and that you override `long getItemId(int position)` in your adapter to return a **unique** Id for every element.

Comment: @XavierRubioJansana thanks for your help, but I think this was not causing this. Please see my answer.

Comment: Weird, but good to know. Thanks for sharing the solution!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ListAdapter not refreshing RecyclerView if I submit the same list with different item order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55263384/listadapter-not-refreshing-recyclerview-if-i-submit-the-same-list-with-different)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This got answered here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/55264063/1181261

Basically, if you submit the same list with different order, it will be ignored. So first you need to `submit(null)` and then submit your re-ordered list.

Comment: When you complete all these recycler view related queries, post some articles on medium which will be highly useful for noobies like me :)

Answer (score 5):

I am concerned that while `.submitList(null)` may have worked for you, it only refreshed your entire RecyclerView without rendering the desired animated list updates.

Solution is to implement the `.submitList( List<T> list)` method inside your ListAdapter as follows:

```
public void submitList(@Nullable List<T> list) {
    mDiffer.submitList(list != null ? new ArrayList<>(list) : null);
}
```

This way you allow the ListAdapter to retain its currentList and have it "diffed" with the newList, thereby the animated updates, as opposed to "diffing" with a `null`.

Comment: By using this, list is not scrolled back to top after sorting and it takes 2-3sec before list order changes (animation shows).

Answer (score 4):

If you look at the javadocs for `AsyncListDiffer`'s `submitList`, you will notice that the second param is a `Runnable` that is executed after the items are submitted to the adapter:

```
/**
 * Pass a new List to the AdapterHelper. Adapter updates will be computed on a background
 * thread.
 * <p>
 * If a List is already present, a diff will be computed asynchronously on a background thread.
 * When the diff is computed, it will be applied (dispatched to the {@link ListUpdateCallback}),
 * and the new List will be swapped in.
 * <p>
 * The commit callback can be used to know when the List is committed, but note that it
 * may not be executed. If List B is submitted immediately after List A, and is
 * committed directly, the callback associated with List A will not be run.
 *
 * @param newList The new List.
 * @param commitCallback Optional runnable that is executed when the List is committed, if
 *                       it is committed.
 */
```

So what you want is this (this is in Kotlin btw):

```
adapter.submitList(items) {
   // This will run after items have been set in the adapter
   recyclerView.scrollToPosition(0)
}
```

or in Java

```
adapter.submitList(items, () -> {
    recyclerView.scrollToPosition(0);
});
```

Comment: This doesn't always work.  In my experience, the commitCallback is often executed before the RecyclerView (well, it's layoutManager) has a chance to actually re-bind and layout it's views, and so the call to `scrollToPosition(0)` ends up having no effect. With Kotlin, you could launch a coroutine and use a `delay()` before calling `scrollToPosition(0)`, but that seems hacky.

Answer (score 0):

Use registerAdapterDataObserver on the adapter in the activity, right after your "mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter)" code:

```
adapter.registerAdapterDataObserver(new RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver() {

    public void onChanged() {
       mRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(0);
    }

    public void onItemRangeRemoved(int positionStart, int itemCount) {
        // same or similar scroll code
        }
    }
});
```

Then unregister the observer in onStop() in the activity.

Comment: What do you mean with "// same or similar scroll code" can you clarify, please?

Comment: @MML Meaning you could put the same code in to scroll the screen up to the top, using "mRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(0);" or maybe you want to scroll the screen down to the bottom of UI so you would add code for that case.